# IMEX in OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string, oledb

I'm trying to read an excel file into a DataTable but IMEX driver does not read all the data in the column. What is the problem in this?

```
OleDbConnection dCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=HDR=YES;Excel 12.0;IMEX=1");
```

Here is the code.

```
OleDbConnection dCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
            fileName + ";Extended Properties=HDR=YES;Excel 12.0;IMEX=1");

OleDbDataAdapter dAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dCon);
dAdp.TableMappings.Add("tbl", "Table");
dAdp.Fill(dSet);
DataTable dT = dSet.Tables[0];

for (int i = 0; i < dT.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     //code for getting the values.
}
```

Comment: What query you are using to fetch data?

Comment: Could you show us a bit more of your code? Also, how many columns are you trying to read and how many are you getting back?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the codes for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's a limit to 255 Characters doing it this way.

You will maybe need to look at using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly for a better solution.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

Comment: Per column mate. Your DataTable Column is short of data as it only passes the first 255 characters using this method.

Comment: Hmm, okay, but the column contains only a two-digit number. It is formatted as text in the excel file.

Comment: OK, Do you mean that you are missing rows?

Comment: Not actually, some of the values are captured but those cells that has a text format were not captured.

Comment: ok, so the text formatted cells only contain 2 digit numbers?

Comment: Most of them, it's 1 to 2 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late for the OP but since I came across it I wanted to add that I believe the Extended Properties section is malformed in this example. Extended Properties needs to be separately enclosed in its own quotes in order to be processed appropriately.

The OPs example used this

> ```
> OleDbConnection dCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
>         fileName + ";Extended Properties=HDR=YES;Excel 12.0;IMEX=1");
> ```

I believe this should have been

> ```
> OleDbConnection dCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
>         fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"HDR=YES;Excel 12.0;IMEX=1\"");
> ```

With this malformed connection it's possible that the IMEX attribute was not being recognized.

See [this MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for information on possible connection string syntax options including those for Extended Properties.